# Answered: Streamlining

Tags: javascript

Context: I am reading from log files data that looks like this:

```
{"action": "tweet", id: 1234, user: "user1", timestamp: 3120}
{"action": "retweet", target_id: 1234, user: "user2", timestamp: 4020}
{"action": "tweet", id: 1235, user: "user3", timestamp: 5320}
{"action": "retweet", target_id: 1235, user: "user4", timestamp: 5820}
{"action": "retweet", target_id: 1235, user: "user2", timestamp: 6540}
```

There's more data in the log files, but these are the fields that matter the most.

I created the following function to read every line of the log file, and detect whether or not a user is a spammer. The criteria for a spammer is:

- Must have no "tweet" actions
- Must have at least one "retweet" action
- All of their retweets must occur within 1000 milliseconds of the target tweet (shown as an association of target_id to id).

The function should return an array of spammers, but not repeat anyone who has already been flagged at least once.

I believe I can clean this up a lot though:

```
identifySpammers = (file_path) => {
  const spammers = [];
  const notSpammers = []; // I"m only using this to track when someone comes up as having a retweet that was after 1000 milliseconds
  let previousId;
  let previousTimeStamp;
  const data = fs.readFileSync(`/${file_path}`, 'utf8').trim().split("\n")
  for(index in data) {
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(data[index]);
    if(parsedData.timestamp - previousTimeStamp >= 1001 && spammers.includes(parsedData.user)) {
      notSpammers.push(parsedData.user)
    } else if (!spammers.includes(parsedData.user) && parsedData.target_id === previousID && parsedData.timestamp - previousTimeStamp < 1001) {
      spammers.push(parsedData.user)
    } else if (parsedData.action === "tweet") {
      previousId = parsedData.id
      previousTimeStamp = parsedData.timestamp
      notSpammers.push(parsedData.user)
    }
  }

  for(let i = 0; i < spammers.length; i++) {
    if(notSpammers.includes(spammers[i])) {
      spammers.splice(i, 1)
    }
  }

  return spammers;
}
```

What I really should be doing is utilizing similar conditions but writing to an object where each key is the user's name and if the value is whether or not they are spammers, so something like:

```
  const spammers = {
    user1: null, // Initialize as null
    user2: false, // Once a user is marked as false, it is impossible for them to ever be considered a spammer.
    user3: true // This could end up being false later on
  }
```

I tried to do this with similar logic to my double array solution, but had no luck.

Based off the above code, if there's any guidance someone can offer where I can come up with a much more efficient object-driven solution, I'd appreciate that. A whole answer is not required, just some advice on how to approach and any ideas beyond that that you may have.

Thanks!

EDIT 1: Cleaned up some mistakes and clarified conditions around when a user is a spammer.
EDIT 2: Expanded log file to demonstrate how a user may be marked as spam earlier, but then passes the necessary conditions to not be one later.

Comment: There are 2 typos on the code: 1) "if(notSpammers.includes(spammers[i])" needs another closing bracket, and 2) previousID / previousId

Comment: I don't undersand the "if / else if / ..." structure. What should happen when there are 2 consecutive "tweet" actions in less than a second?

Comment: Updated with fixes.

If a user makes a "tweet" action, they are considered not a spammer. The only way someone can be considered a spammer is if they make zero "Tweet" actions.

Comment: Cleaned up the requirements a bit, let me know if it could be more clear.

Comment: Your current version does not comply with your requirements: https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/p89vkbLa/ See how user1 is considered spammer even when he has a tweet.

Comment: I will provide more information. It does work, it's just that this user later on is marked as a not spammer. Let me give some better info.

Comment: Think I found the issue there, my bad.

Comment: Maybe it works with your data, but the jsfiddle I linked proves your code has a bug: it does not adds a user to "notSpammers" array until that user has already be added to "spammers" array. So users with legit tweets and a last "fast retweet" are marked as spammers.

Comment: I added another line that should account for that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have refactored in a more clean code way and using the proposed data structure:

```js
var data = [
 {"action": "tweet", id: 1234, user: "user1", timestamp: 1341414},
 {"action": "retweet", target_id: 1234, user: "user2", timestamp: 1341415},
 {"action": "tweet", id: 1235, user: "user3", timestamp: 2341414},
 {"action": "retweet", target_id: 1235, user: "user1", timestamp: 2341415},
]

const isSpammerByUser = {};
let previousId;
let previousTimeStamp;
for(index in data) {
  const parsedData = data[index];
  const user = parsedData.user;
  const isUserASpammer = (isSpammerByUser[user] === true);
  const hasUserProvenToNotBeASpammer = (isSpammerByUser[user] === false);
  const isFastAction = (parsedData.timestamp - previousTimeStamp < 1001);
  const isRetweetFromPrevious = (parsedData.target_id === previousId);
  
  if (parsedData.action === "tweet") {
    isSpammerByUser[user] = false;
    previousId = parsedData.id
    previousTimeStamp = parsedData.timestamp

  } else if(isUserASpammer && !isFastAction) {
    isSpammerByUser[user] = false;

  } else if (!hasUserProvenToNotBeASpammer && isRetweetFromPrevious && isFastAction) {
    isSpammerByUser[user] = true;
  }
}

const spammers = [];
for (user in isSpammerByUser)
  if (isSpammerByUser[user])
    spammers.push(user);

console.log("spammers: " + spammers.join(","));
```

Comment: Very nice! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help, and enjoy your best answer :)

Comment: Using variables with meaningfull names for the complex if conditions is a good clean code practice :). It is less efficient (you're evaluating conditions that you may not need) but it's more readable and human time is more expensive than machine time. If efficiency is a concern, you can refactor the variables with functions (with the same name as the variables) inside the if conditions.

Comment: Yeah, I rather go for clean code practice vs. efficiency for the problem I'm trying to solve.